# How to download a public certificate from Amazon Certificate Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-acm

I have a public SSL certificate in Amazon Certificate Manager. I want to upload this certificate to an instance that is not hosted in amazon. How can i download the certificate from Amazon Certificate Manager. I need to download both certificate and private key

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**You cannot download the private key for an SSL certificate from ACM - ACM certificates are only for use on AWS ALBs, CloudFront, API gateway and other AWS infrastructure. ACM keep hold of the private key and will use it whereever the certificate is used.**

You can download the certificate using `awscli` with `aws acm get-certificate --certificate-arn arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:123456789012:certificate/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012`. This will get you Public certificate.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/get-certificate.html

Comment: Thank you for information. Do you know how can i setup downloaded public certificate in another server (no in aws) ? according to my knowledge, without the private key i cannot use the downloaded certificate in another server

Comment: @Nipu You can only use ACM SSL certificates with AWS Load Balancers, CloudFront and API Gateway. it is not possible obtain the certificate from ACM and install it directly on a server.

Comment: Whether we could use this certificate for rabbitMQ ?

Comment: @MarkB Note that this is old info. You can now use export-certificate to get the private key as well.

Comment: @Ariel That's only for private certificates created by ACM for internal use. This question is about public certificates.

Comment: @MarkB Ah, I did not understand that nuance, thank you for the clarification. Suggestion: maybe update your answer to mention export-certificate and the nuance of using it?