# Export public key from AWS ACM?

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS ACM provides an API to export the public certificate via CLI.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/export-certificate.html

[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562148/how-to-download-a-public-certificate-from-amazon-certificate-manager)

When certificates are renewed, the exported ones will not remain valid, and theres' no API to export the public key.

Is there a way to extract, or otherwise retrieve the public key from an ACM public certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AWS ACM provides an API to export the public certificate via CLI.

Sadly this is not the case. The link is for [AWS ACM Private CA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm-pca/latest/userguide/PcaWelcome.html) which is related to AWS ACM, but its not the same:

> Exports a private certificate issued by a **private certificate authority** (CA) for use anywhere.

In short, `AWS ACM` certificates  **can't be exported**, while those from `AWS ACM Private CA` can. However, SSL certs from `AWS ACM Private CA` are not public, can't be used on the internet and are not free.

If you require to have control of a private key from your SSL cert, you need to get it from a third party, not from ACM.

I assume that you want private key, not public. Public key you can get from a browser when you connect to your website protected by SSL cert from ACM.

Comment: Thanks. The requirement is to get a public key for public key cryptographic purposes for AWS backend. I guess that won't work with default ACM certificates, specially with managed rotation.